# Visual Studio - unsure about exporting projects

Tags: c++, directx, static-libraries, executable, visual-studio-2013

I'm new on here, but not a total beginner to programming. I got a book on creating a 2D DirectX game engine so I could expand my programming knowledge, however I am new to C++ and DirectX itself, so I'm afraid I'm a bit clueless on working with multiple project files and headers. I decided to develop my game engine in a proper development environment, so I got VS2013 Professional though the Dreamspark program.

As I said, I haven't worked with something like VS before, so I'm hitting issues with getting my game engine running and I'm not sure what to do. The book said that if I get all my code down correctly (in 3 .cpp source files, 3 headers and 1 main .cpp source file to initialize my engine in a blank game project) the program should compile fine, and it does. The issue is that I only get the resultant .obj files and the project's static library file to appear in my project folder. I don't know what I have to do to get the project to compile the executable needed to actually run this 'blank game' with the engine.

The actual project solution was taken from the disk which came with the book, I wrote my code on top of that solution as my own was causing linker errors. The project properties show that the project is defined as a .lib project, so how is this supposed to work?

I apologize if this is a simple problem, but I'm only used to working with 1 file console applications in C, this is a big jump for me but I'd like to understand how I'm meant to get an .exe created from this project, I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me how this sort of .lib project works. I can post the code if it's necessary, but there's 7 files of it so it's quite long. Thanks!

Comment: A lib project does not produce an exe and does not normally have a main cpp file. To test a lib you need a second project (probably the main cpp) that produces an exe. The second project would link in the lib created by the first project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm trying to use the main.cpp in a new Win32 project, the book doesn't explicitly state to create a second project, but I can see that it's what I needed to do.

However I can't get the Win32 project to compile, I get no syntax errors but I'm getting a few LNK2019 errors. I have no idea what to do with them, I know there isn't a single solution to linker errors but maybe someone could suggest what the cause might be?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
As the project contains a main.cpp it looks like it is not meant to be a library-project.

In VS2013 you can switch the type of a project by

- In your `Solution Explorer` (on the left side by default) rightclick onto the project
- Select the item `Properties` from Context Menu (should be on the bottom)
- Select the category `General`
- In the section `Project Defaults` change the `Configuration Type` to `Executable (.exe)`

**Solution 2:**
It could be possible that the executable is stored somewhere else after a successful build. Check what is configured as output directory:

- In your `Solution Explorer` (on the left side by default) rightclick onto the project
- Select the item `Properties` from Context Menu (should be at the bottom)
- Select the category `General`
- In section `General` there should be an `Output Directory` defined (At the top of the configuration). Per default it should be something like `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\`

*I'm using VS2013 Express, but it should work with Prof too. I'm also using a German edition, hope I translated everything well.*